# Accessing TextWatcher in another class - nullpointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-textwatcher

I have one activity and one of its function logic is calculated in another class, here i calculate when something is entered in the edit text field, i use a text watcher.

MainActivity code:

```
public class UnitConverter extends AppCompatActivity {
    public EditText input;
    .
    ......
    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etInput);
    .........
    case Sample :
         new AnotherClass();
}
```

am using textwatcher on this `input` field,

AnotherClass code:

```
public class AnotherClass {
UnitConverter ac = new UnitConverter();
public AnotherClass() {
    ac.input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {
     }
  }
}
```

am getting a null pointer error,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do it the way you are doing?

Comment: is there any better way of doing it, if then suggest me that

Comment: Just do in UnitConverter activity class itself

Comment: It will be to long, i want to split it to different files...

Comment: you have input in unitconverter and searching it in anotherclass why?

Comment: where are you getting reference of view i.e ac.input ?

Comment: am accessing 'UnitConverter ac = new UnitConverter();` and using `ac.input` @KhizarHayat @KDeogharkar

Comment: new UnitConverter is intance not view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass your activity reference to another class to like below:

MainActivity code:

```
public class UnitConverter extends AppCompatActivity {
    public EditText input;
    .
    ......
    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etInput);
    .........
    case Sample :
        new AnotherClass(UnitConverter.this);
}
```

AnotherClass code:

```
public class AnotherClass {
    public AnotherClass(UniteConverter ac) {
    ac.input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                              int before, int count) {
      }
  }
}
```